# "cannot find symbol"/"non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        create("Maze.txt");
    }

}

public class Maze {
    private final int Max_Maze_Row=20;
    private final int Max_Maze_Column=50;
    public char[][] maze =new char[Max_Maze_Column-1][Max_Maze_Row-1];


    public Maze(){

    }

    public void create(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner fileinput=new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));
        fileinput.useDelimiter("");

        while(fileinput.hasNextLine()){
            int row=0;int col=0;
            String line_content=fileinput.nextLine();
            for(col=0;col<Max_Maze_Column;col++){
                maze[row][col]=line_content.charAt(col);
            }
            row++;
            fileinput.close();

        }

        System.out.println(maze);
    }

}
```

So basically, I am trying to create a Maze class which will read from a text file the contents of a 20x50 maze (this will be stored in a 2d array).
I defined the method create which will read in the maze contents and create the 2D array.
I have the code for it, which I thought would be correct.
However, when I call the create method in the main function, I get the "cannot find symbol" error. Also, once I make the create() method static, I get the nonstatic variable error. Why does this happen?
Any help on the error or tips on my create method would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: `create` is a method in `Maze`, not in `Main` - also it is not `static`

Comment: @UnholySheep does it matter if it is a method in Maze even if its declared as public? Shouldn't I be able to call the method anywhere if its public? Also, what is the significance of static? I had it as static, but I get all sorts of errors in the create method once I put it as static.

Comment: If you had two classes which both defined a method called `create` how would you be able to tell which one you are calling?

Comment: If you put all your code in main, which is static, you end up forcing all your code to be static. The idea is your main should set up some environment such as logging and initial app state and even check STDIN for optargs before creating your main app object that it then invokes. It handles results and/or exceptions in some manner to control how the app is exited.

Comment: Lol I saw this randomly and... I don't code in java anymore, but it's super funny!

Answer (score 0):

`create` isn't static and therefore you need an instance of `Maze`, for example:

```
  new Maze().create("Maze.txt");
```

Notice that normally each class will be in different java file.

Comment: Can you explain to me the significance of having the method as static vs leaving it out? As soon as I make it static, I get errors such as non-static variable Max_Maze_Column cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: @Gary Kim don't use static

Comment: The specifications for the program actually said I need to define the create method as static, only reason I changed it temporarily was because I was getting errors I didn't know how to fix right away (I was going to come back to it later). I read materials on the explanation of static, but I really couldn't grasp the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You must create object of the class before calling that class method. like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Maze maze = new Maze();
        maze.create("Maze.txt");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things "wrong" with your code sample, but most are about style, patterns, etc. and not necessarily technical problems.

As others have said, you need to create a new object of `Maze` type in order to be able to call the `create()` method.

On the other hand, why call a no-arg constructor and then an `init` method (called `create`, here) which loads the maze from the disk. Instead, why not have a `Maze` constructor which takes the filename and loads the maze?

If I were designing this class, I might instead declare the `create` method like this:

```
public static Maze load(String filename)
```

This method would instantiate a new `Maze` object, fill it with data, and return it to the caller. I like this "factory pattern" because you might want to implement `Maze` in different ways. The factory method gives you more flexibility than a constructor, because the factory-method allows you to return whatever concrete `Maze` subclass you want, and you can change your mind later. Calling a constructor locks you into using that specific class.

Completely unrelated to the method to creating a `Maze` object and calling its `init` method, you are probably allocating more heap memory than necessary by always allocating a `char[][]` array at the maximum allowable size. Instead of allocating the memory immediately upon object construction, perhaps you should wait until you know how big the maze is going to be.

If the maze-file says it's a 10x10 maze, you are still allocating 49x20 character array, which is much more than you actually need.

There's no particular reason a `Maze` constructor shouldn't accept the size of the maze as parameters, and then only allocate as much memory as you need.

It's odd to see `MAX_SIZE` used like this:

```
new char[MAX_SIZE - 1][MAX_SIZE - 1]
```

Why subtract 1? Usually, you'd see an allocation like this:

```
new char[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE]
```

And then a range-check like this:

```
if(x <= maze.length - 1)
    // x is in range
```

or

```
if(x < maze.length)
    // x is in range
```

I hope that helps you build a better `Maze` class.

Comment: After several months, I came back to this and my question was so hilarious. I forgot all  the Java. I will say that I like your comment about the design pattern. And I do have certain opinion on that now. But there's no way a guy who dabbled with Java for a couple of weeks can ever understand those details. Thanks for your answer, I can finally appreciate the details.

Comment: When I asked the question at that time, I wish I was more aware of what was going on. At the time, I just wanted to make a maze lol. Was clueless about all the details.

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        **Maze.**create("Maze.txt");
    }

}

public class Maze {
    private final int Max_Maze_Row=20;
    private final int Max_Maze_Column=50;
    public char[][] maze =new char[Max_Maze_Column-1][Max_Maze_Row-1];


    public Maze(){

    }

    public **static** void create(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner fileinput=new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));
        fileinput.useDelimiter("");

        while(fileinput.hasNextLine()){
            int row=0;int col=0;
            String line_content=fileinput.nextLine();
            for(col=0;col<Max_Maze_Column;col++){
                maze[row][col]=line_content.charAt(col);
            }
            row++;
            fileinput.close();

        }

        System.out.println(maze);
    }

}
```

Comment: This won't compile